# How to capture all WKWebView traffic using URLProtocol (macOS only)

Tags: swift, macos, wkwebview

I am writing an application for experimentation and analysis that identifies all http and https requests (GET, POST, PUT, etc) and content, URLs, media, etc.

This is whether the traffic was initiated by the user or done in the background by javascript.  This is something WebKit can do natively with developer extras enable but the goal is to have full controllable visibility from my own browser.  I do not need to cache anything, only see and capture the activity in real time.

I have a functioning application but only traffic from "func canInit(with request: URLRequest)" is seen, so I am not seeing all the activity that happens in the background.

I've read many blogs and documentation about URLProtocol, WKURLScheme and WKNavigationDelegate.  Apple doesnt allow http or https with WKURLSchemeHandler and the WKNavigationDelegate delegates only capture some high-level traffic.  I've also read that applications are doing this by swizzling methods to get the same results.  I should be able to get this without messing around under the hood with swizzling but if necessary, I will.

***The code below works but does not capture all transactions.***

startLoading() is never called, which should happen once we decide to handle the request in "func canInit(with request: URLRequest)" but that does not happen.

How can I see **all transactions** such as (GET, POST, PUT, etc) and content, URLs, media, etc using **NATIVE** code?  Below is a image of the desired outcome, to see all the traffic in real time.

[image: Desired Outcome]

```swift
/*
    Identify all http and https requests (GET, POST, PUT, etc) and content, URLs, media, etc.
    whether they were initiated by the user or done in the background by javascript.
    This is something WebKit can do natively but the goal is to have full controllable visibility
    I do not need to cache anything, only see and capture the activity in real time.
*/

import Foundation
import WebKit

class CustomURLProtocol: URLProtocol, URLSessionDelegate {
    var connection  : NSURLConnection?
    var data        : Data?
    var response    : URLResponse?
    var dataTask    : URLSessionDataTask?
    static var requestCount = 0

    lazy var session: URLSession = {
        let config = URLSession.shared.configuration
        return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
    }()
    
    static func printHeaders(allHeaders: [AnyHashable : Any]?) {
        print("Begin Headers: ****")
        for (key, value) in allHeaders ?? [:] {
            print("\(key): \(value)")
        }
        print("End Headers: ****")
    }
    
    static func logRequest(callingFunction: String = #function, statusCode: String = "N/A",
                           request: URLRequest, response: URLResponse? = nil){
        // Log the request **OR** response, status code and trace which class method made the call
        var bodyStr  = "Empty Body"
        var urlStr   = "No URL"
        var headers  = [:] as [AnyHashable : Any]?
        var logType  = "Request    "
        
        /*
            Get the header of the request **OR** the response.
            The headers in the request and response are in different locations and hash types.
            allHTTPHeaderFields is [String : String]? so normalize it to [AnyHashable : Any]?
            then pass it to "printHeaders"
        */
        if (response != nil) {
            // This is actually a RESPONSE, so get its header
            headers = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.allHeaderFields
            logType = "Response   "
        } else {
            // This is a request, so get its header
            headers  = (request.allHTTPHeaderFields!) as [AnyHashable : Any]?
        }

        if (request.httpBody != nil) { bodyStr = String(data: request.httpBody!, encoding: .utf8)!}
        if (request.url != nil) { urlStr = request.url!.absoluteString}
        print("Function    = \(callingFunction)")
        print("\(logType) : #\(requestCount)")
        print("Method      : \(request.httpMethod ?? "None")")
        print("Body        : \(bodyStr)")
        print("Status Code : \(statusCode)")
        print("URL         = \(urlStr)") // print("URL: \(request.url!)")
        CustomURLProtocol.printHeaders(allHeaders:headers)
        print("--------------\n\n")
    }
    

    
    override class func canInit(with request: URLRequest) -> Bool {
//        Return true if the request should be intercepted
//        We can add additional logic here to only intercept certain types of requests
        CustomURLProtocol.logRequest(request: request)
        
        var isHandled = true
        if (URLProtocol.property(forKey: "CustomURLProtocolHandledKey", in: request as URLRequest) != nil){
            // prevent recursive loop
            isHandled =  false
        }
//        if (request.url?.scheme == "http" || request.url?.scheme == "https") &&
//            URLProtocol.property(forKey: "CustomURLProtocolHandledKey", in: request as URLRequest) != nil{
//            isHandled =  false
//        }

        requestCount += 1 // count all request but handle our custom types
        return isHandled
    }
    

    override class func canonicalRequest(for request: URLRequest) -> URLRequest {
        // Return the canonical version of the request
        CustomURLProtocol.logRequest(request: request)
        return request
    }
    
    override func startLoading() {
        //  If we are handling the request, copy it, update with a custom key and pass
        //  along so we can let it be handled by forwarding it
        CustomURLProtocol.logRequest(request: request) // Log the request data here
        // Forward the request to the original destination
        let newRequest = (self.request as NSURLRequest).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
        URLProtocol.setProperty(true, forKey: "CustomURLProtocolHandledKey", in: newRequest)
        
        var newResponse = self.response
        if (newResponse == nil){
            newResponse = HTTPURLResponse(url: request.url!, statusCode: 301,
                                          httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1", headerFields: ["Location": "https://www.example.com"])!
        }
        self.client?.urlProtocol(self, wasRedirectedTo: newRequest as URLRequest, redirectResponse: newResponse!)
        self.dataTask = self.session.dataTask(with: newRequest as URLRequest)
        self.dataTask?.resume()
    }
    
    override func stopLoading() {
        // Cancel the connection and log it
        CustomURLProtocol.logRequest(request: request)
        self.connection?.cancel()
        self.connection = nil
    }
    
    override class func requestIsCacheEquivalent( _ a: URLRequest, to b: URLRequest ) -> Bool{
        return super.requestIsCacheEquivalent( a, to: b ) // we dont care to cache, just pass it along
    }
}

extension CustomURLProtocol: NSURLConnectionDelegate {
    
    func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive response: URLResponse){
        // Store the response and log the status code and headers
        self.response = response
        let statusCode = String("Status code: \((response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? 0)")
        CustomURLProtocol.logRequest(statusCode: statusCode, request: request, response: response)
        self.client!.urlProtocol(self, didReceive: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .notAllowed)
        self.data = Data()
    }
    
    func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didReceive data: Data) {
        // Accumulate the data
        print("function \(#function)")
        print("--------------\n\n")
        self.client!.urlProtocol(self, didLoad: data)
        if self.data == nil {
            self.data = Data()
        }
        self.data?.append(data)
    }
    
    func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Log the error and notify the client that the request has failed
        print("function \(#function)")
        print("Error: \(error)")
        print("--------------\n\n")
        self.client?.urlProtocol(self, didFailWithError: error)
    }
    
    func connectionDidFinishLoading(_ connection: NSURLConnection) {
        // Log the final response data and notify the client that the request has completed
        print("function \(#function)")
        if let data = self.data {
            print("Body: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)")
        } else {
            print("Body is NIL")
        }
        print("--------------\n\n")
        self.client?.urlProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
    }
}

class TrafficInspector: NSViewController {
    private let webView = WKWebView()
    
    func deleteCache(){
        let websiteDataTypes = WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()
        let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
        WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: websiteDataTypes, modifiedSince: date as Date, completionHandler: {
            print("remove all cached data")
        })
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // load our webview
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        URLProtocol.registerClass(CustomURLProtocol.self)
        self.webView.configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "developerExtrasEnabled")
        
        deleteCache()
        // Set up web view
        view.addSubview(webView)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        //        webView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
        
        // Load a webpage using the intercepted URLProtocol instance
        let urlStr  = "https://cnn.com"
        let url = URL(string:urlStr)!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
 

        /*
         func startLoading() doesnt get called unless I do the following
         
         let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
         config.protocolClasses = [CustomURLProtocol.self]
         let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
         let task = session.dataTask(with: url)
         task.resume()
         */
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you found an answer yet? Please post it as the answer if so.

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let contextController = NSClassFromString("WKBrowsingContextController") as? NSObjectProtocol else { return }
 let selector = Selector(("registerSchemeForCustomProtocol:"))

 if contextController.responds(to: selector) {
     _ = contextController.perform(selector, with: "http")
 }

 if contextController.responds(to: selector) {
     _ = contextController.perform(selector, with: "https")
 }
 URLProtocol.registerClass(CustomURLProtocol.self)
```

The only problem with this solution is that we are using private API which might be not welcome in future by Apple review.

The other solution might be to intercept http/https requests in JS (XHR) and change their scheme to your custom. Then you are free to use WKURLSchemeHandler